# In windows XP I need a free program to take two audio channels and export them as one for video streaming. Any ideas?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio, mixer

I'm basically going to be streaming what comes through the TV through a pinnacle capture card, what comes from skype, and then what comes from my microphone and I need these three audio tracks to be combined into one to stream online.

However, I want to do this as cheap as possible, is there any free software to accomplish this task?

Comment: Welcome.  Shopping/Software Requests are considered Not Constructive and Off-Topic here on SU as per the FAQ.  If you have a specific question about a specific problem we'll be happy to try and help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried audacity?
Its free and I suppose it can do what you desire..
Check this out : http://www.ehow.com/how_8494183_put-two-tracks-together-audacity.html